# Navigation Controller Header is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

So, here I basically have this layout

[image]

but when I build successfully I am not able to see the title of the navigation controller.

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Split the 2 questions, get to the point (no intro needed), smaller images, save screen from simulator (command-s) instead of screen grab, and if you want screen grab, use command-shit-4 + space-bar + click for whole window.

Comment: Tks for the edit @SwiftArchitect

Comment: My pleasure. Please post the second question separately... (I removed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to emulate:

[image: Root tab bar controller]

- Set the `UITabBarController` as *is Initial View Controller*
- add a relationship to each scene, whether it is a `UINavigationController` or not
- If a scene is a `UINavigationController`, it will behave like any root navigation controller, with its own view stack, back button, an so forth.

---

Running the app above, then tapping on *Item 2* will present this navigation controller:

[image: Named controller]

---

If you cannot make the `UITabBarController` the *initial View Controller* at launch, you can make it become **root** later on using this technique:

```swift
let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id")
                        as? UIViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = newViewController
```

This will present the architecture above, albeit without animation (nor any way to navigate back). Perfect for onboarding or login screens.

---

Tested on **Xcode 7+**, **iOS 9+**

Comment: Well u see , there is a login page infront of it.. So i can't make tabbar controller as the initial view controller

Comment: Yup that works.. what I did is to remove the navigation controller for the initial one and then added a cancel button to the sign up page.

Comment: There is a another solution for login pages: on login completion, use something like `self.view.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController`. It will replace your original vc with the new vc (no animation)

Comment: Sorry, to bother. But ur above code where should I put it? I tried putting it in the viewDidLoad of a new file i created for the MainTabBarController.

Comment: Use the above code in your `IBAction` handler where you would normally push a new view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Make your TabBar Controller the initial view, And make sure to remove the navigation controller that's linked to it, Then it should work fine.