# IOS Change rootview controller after login

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a side drawer in my application which required me to set the root view controller in my application delegate. i am now working on a login screen. to access the login screen i had to comment out where i set the root view controller. How can i set the root view controller once the user has logged in?

Below is my app delegate(or part of it)

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as!ViewController

    let drawerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DrawerViewController") as!DrawerViewController

    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: drawerViewController)
    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)

    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

    //window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

i have a method to handle the segue after successful login but don't know how to set the root controller out side the delegate.
in summary the navigation works if i uncomment the `//window!.rootViewController = centerContainer` line but then cant access the login view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can swap the root view controller dynamically:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController = newVc
```

A simple example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951197/218152.
A complete example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32109767/218152.

Swapping the `rootViewController` is a one time operation: no back button, no animation.

Answer (score 0):

To change rootViewController after login screen

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = viewController
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

*Make sure you have set 'HomeViewController' in storyboard as Storyboard ID of HomeViewController*